# Profile page .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have problem with redirect. 
Please help.

from: http://example.com/users/{username}/profile

to:  http://example.com/profile/{username}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/(profile)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC]
```